# Pooling newly created aws sqs messages

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, amazon-sqs

```
@Async
public void scanFile() {
    log.info("Start scanning");
    String queueUrl = sqs.getQueueUrl("bucket-antivirus").getQueueUrl();
    List<Message> messages = sqs.receiveMessage(new ReceiveMessageRequest()
                .withQueueUrl(queueUrl)
                .withWaitTimeSeconds(20))
                    .getMessages();
        for (Message message : messages) {
            try {
                // move clear file to file bucket
            }
            ...
            log.info("Scanning complete");
        }
}
```

When a user uploads a file, SQS will receive a message. The application will move the file to a new bucket.

But I cant get the most recent message even I added waiting time for the SQS client. With multiple tests, after I upload a file, I only get the message of the previous file before. How do I let SQS client wait for the most recent message/the message of the specific file?

Comment: On a related note - "When a user uploads a file, SQS will receive a message. The application will move the file to a new bucket." -- why are you going through SQS for this? Cloudwatch Events or Lambda may be a better fit for this particular process

Answer (score 0):

A standard SQS queue **does not have a guaranteed order of delivery**. So if you ask for a message (or messages), you might get old ones or new ones (but they are generally in-order). This should be fine, because a queue-based system should not rely on the order of messages. (SQS FIFO queues do, however, guarantee order.)

By the sounds of it, if you are receiving a message based on an 'old file', then you have not correctly processed a message that was previously retrieved. When your process retrieves a message from SQS, it should do the necessary work, then call `DeleteMessage()` to **remove it from the queue**.

Your use-case actually sounds like a perfect situation for using an **AWS Lambda function**. When a new object is added to an S3 bucket, you can configure it to trigger a Lambda function (instead of sending an SQS message). The Lambda function could then process the file. This is a simpler solution than having your code continually polling the SQS queue.

Comment: Order of message is not the problem. When there is no message in the queue, the `sqsclient.getMessages()` does not wait for the message in flight, it returns immediately an empty list even I set `withWaitTime`.

Comment: waitasec - so even `withWaitTimeSeconds(20)`, it's returning *instantly* (ie: less than a second) with no messages? That doesn't sound right. Based on docs and my years of experience with SQS, `withWaitTimeSeconds` is supposed to wait until the wait time expires or a message is available. It sounds like there's something else going on here...

Comment: @Krease Is that caused by `@Async`? Because I can get the message after I add `Thread.sleep(5000)` to wait for 5 sec before `getMessages()`.

Comment: Could be - are you asynchronously publishing the message too?